# How to rewrite this query without the IN keyword?

Tags: sql, mysql

I wrote this query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM etape_prospection INNER JOIN type_prospection 
ON etape_prospection.type_prosp_id = type_prospection.type_prosp_id 
WHERE etape_prospection.prosp_id IN (select transfert.prosp_id 
                                     from transfert 
                                     where transfert.user_code ='3' 
                                     AND transfert.date_transfert='2012-01-20');
```

My boss doesn't like this query because of the `IN` keyword which makes a full table scan , so how to rewrite it without the `IN` keyword ?

Comment: use EXPLAIN to be sure it actually makes a table full scan. consider creating an index for (transfert.user_code and transfert.date_transfert).

Comment: post the tables please, and what the query is supposed to do.

Comment: I think there is no need to do `EXPLAIN`. My boss is categoric : don't use the `IN` !

Comment: Then your boss needs to read some Codd's book regarding the principles of relational databases

Comment: don't learn nothing from your boss then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` instead of `IN` this is usually cheaper than `IN` and sometimes also cheaper than the `INNER JOIN` suggested in other answers:

```
SELECT * 
FROM etape_prospection INNER JOIN type_prospection 
ON etape_prospection.type_prosp_id = type_prospection.type_prosp_id 
WHERE EXISTS (select 1
               FROM transfert 
               WHERE transfert.prosp_id = etape_prospection.prosp_id
               AND transfert.user_code ='3' 
               AND transfert.date_transfert='2012-01-20');
```

Also (reminded by the comment by danihp on [one of the other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8940757/466862)): using `INNER JOIN` can have the unwanted/unintended side effect of duplicating rows in the resultset if there are multiple rows in `transfert` that satisfy these conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * 
FROM etape_prospection INNER JOIN type_prospection 
ON etape_prospection.type_prosp_id = type_prospection.type_prosp_id inner join transfert 
on etape_prospection.prosp_id = transfert.prosp_id 
where transfert.user_code ='3'  AND transfert.date_transfert='2012-01-20'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another Inner JOIN

```
SELECT etape_prospection.*,type_prospection.*
FROM etape_prospection 
INNER JOIN type_prospection 
  ON etape_prospection.type_prosp_id = type_prospection.type_prosp_id 
INNER JOIN transfert 
  ON etape_prosection.pros_id = transfert.prosp_id
WHERE transfert.user_code ='3' 
  AND transfert.date_transfert='2012-01-20';
Group BY transfert.pros_id
```

Also changed the SELECT to do not display the transfert columns

Comment: This is a close solution. But, in my opinion, is still wrong because perhaps a `etape_prospection` has multiple `transfer`. In this case your approach will return more rows that original query. It is not?

Comment: So I must write first the table which has the many numbers of joins ?

Comment: @frederic not you also can write the transert table on first position

Comment: @danihp yes you are right .. to exclude that a group by is needed

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should work:

```
        SELECT * 
          FROM etape_prospection 
    INNER JOIN type_prospection ON etape_prospection.type_prosp_id = type_prospection.type_prosp_id 
    INNER JOIN transfert on transfert.prosp_id = etape_prospection.prosp_id 
         WHERE transfert.user_code ='3' 
           AND transfert.date_transfert='2012-01-20';
```

However the IN doesn't actually gives always a Full Table Scan, I suspect you're missing an index. The in clause has the benefit of almost fixed execution time, while adding the extra join will make the query dependant on transfert table's cardinality (n° of tuples).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT * FROM etape_prospection 
INNER JOIN type_prospection ON etape_prospection.type_prosp_id = type_prospection.type_prosp_id  
LEFT JOIN transfert ON transfert.prosp_id = etape_prospection.prosp_id
WHERE transfert.user_code ='3' AND transfert.date_transfert='2012-01-20';
```